# Proving $A$ to be independent of $B\cap C,$ if $A,B$ and $C$ are independent events.

Tags: probability

> Let $A,B$ and $C$ be independent events. Show that $A$ is independent
>   of both $B \cap C$ and $B \cup C$.

So I have given that $P(A\cap B \cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$, according to the definition of independent events. Now I have that

\begin{align}
P(A\cap (B\cup C)) &= P((A\cap B) \cup (A\cap C))\\
&= P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap C) - P(((A\cap B) \cap (A\cap C))\\
&= P(A)P(B) + P(A)P(C) - P(A\cap B \cap C)\\
&= P(A)\left(P(B) + P(C) - P(B\cap C)\right) 
+ \left(P(A)P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B \cap C)\right)\\
&= P(A)P(B\cup C) + \left[P(A)P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B \cap C)\right] \\
&= P(A)P(B\cup C)+\left[P(A)P(B)P(C) - P(A)P(B)P(C)\right] \\
&=P(A)P(B\cup C).
\end{align}

However, how would I show that $A$ is independent of $B\cap C$? Wouldn't this just follow from the definition?

$$P(A\cap B \cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)=P(A)P(B\cap C)=P(A\cap (B\cap C))?$$

Comment: Yes, you are right, but showing the second equality is easier than the first one, so you may invert their order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm late, but this question just appeared in my "Related" column.

Your proof is **incorrect**. From the hypothesis $P(A\cap B \cap C)=P(A)\,P(B)\,P(C)$ it does not follow that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are pairwise independent. As shown by [this example](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~ggeorge/MathGaz04.pdf), you cannot infer any of the following:
$$
\begin{align}
P(A\cap B)=P(A)\,P(B)\\
P(A\cap C)=P(A)\,P(C)\\
P(B\cap C)=P(B)\,P(C)
\end{align}
$$

What you need is a stronger hypothesis: $A$, $B$ and $C$ mutually independent.